# Best practice to import data from SQL server to Hive through Sqoop

Tags: sql-server, hive, sqoop, cloudera-cdh, data-import

We are working on to import data from MS SQL Server to hive through Sqoop. If we use the incremental & append mode which is the requirement then we need to specify the --last-value of the row id which we inserted last time.

I have to update about 100 tables into Hive.

1. What is the practice to save the value of row id for all tables and specify in the sqoop --last-value command ?
2. Why does not Sqoop itself check the row id of the source & destination table, finally update the rows onwards the last row id value of the destination table?
3. If i save the last value of row id for all tables in a hive table and want to use those values in Sqoop job then how it's possible?

All and above, i want to automate the data importing job so that i do not have to provide the value manually for each table data import per day

Any pointers ?

Thanks

Comment: RTFM, especially chapters 10-11-12 http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.2/SqoopUserGuide.html#_saved_jobs

Comment: Caveat: the Sqoop 1 "metastore" is a very, very, ugly thing that uses a *deprecated* version of HSQLDB (doesn't even support backups, yuck) and proudly claims that its metadata is in `version (null)` (i.e. not even a beta)